# Setting Enviroment Variables Dynamically on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I am currently looking for a way to set enviroment variables in Linux via a simple shell script. Within the script I am currently using the 'export' command, however this only has scope within the script where system-wide scope is needed.

Is there anyway I can do this via a shell script, or will another method need to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a shell script, it executes in a sub-shell. What you need is to execute it in the context of the current shell, by sourcing it with:

```
source myshell.sh
```

or:

```
. myshell.sh
```

The latter is my preferred approach since I'm inherently lazy.

If you're talking about system-wide scope inasmuch as you want to affect everybody, you'll need to put your commands in a place where they're sourced at login time (or shell creation time), `/etc/profile` for example. Where you put your commands depends on the shell being used.

You can find out what scripts get executed by examining the `man` page for your shell:

```
man bash
```

The `bash` shell, when invoked as a login shell (including as a non-login shell but with the `--login` parameter), will use `/etc/profile` and the first of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`.

Non-login `bash` shells will use. unless invoked with `--norc` or `--rcfile <filename>`, the files `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

I'm pretty certain it's even *more* convoluted than that depending on how the shell is run, but that's as far as my memory stretches. The `man` page should detail it all.

Comment: Unfortunatly the script is to be ran from a different application with several arguments (it will also be ran more than once per-login)

Comment: You can't affect the environment of other processes directly so you may need to find another way if the bash startup execution chain is insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your script check for the existence of something like /var/myprog/env-vars-to-load and 'source' it then unlink it if it exists, perhaps using trap and a signal. Its hard to say, I'm not familiar with your program.

There is no way to 'inject' environmental variables into another process' address space, so you'll have to find some method of IPC which will can instruct the process on what to set.

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental aspect of environment variables is that you cannot affect the environment for any process but your own and child processes that you spawn. You can't create a script that sets "system wide" environment variables that somehow become usable by other processes.

Answer (score 0):

On the shell prompt:

```
$ source script.sh
```

And set the env vars in script.sh

Answer (score 0):

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "export MY_VAR=STACK_OVERFLOW" >> $HOME/.bashrc
. $HOME/.bashrc
sh task.sh
```

task.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $MY_VAR
```

Add executable rights:

```
chmod +x test.sh task.sh
```

And lauch test.sh

```
./test.sh
```

Result:

```
STACK_OVERFLOW
```